# How to end a whole program

Tags: c++

I have a pretty simple C++ console program. It's working fine, but I have some issues. 
I have 2 functions. First function called "input" asks from user to input numbers from 6 to 10. In that function I declared:

```
if ((a[i][j] < 6) || (a[i][j] > 10))
{
    cout<<"Invalid input!";
    return 0; 
}
```

Second function called "output", prints out those numbers from first function.

In the main it is like:

```
int main ()
{
    ...
    input (matrix, number);
    output (matrix, nubmer);
}
```

My question is this. When I input number that isn't 6-10, my program still do "output" function, so it prints some random numbers. How can I break whole program in exact time when input rules are broken? Without any random output and stuff, just to print "Invalid output", then to start program from the start?

Comment: Post complete code. Does it print 'Invalid input' in first place?

Comment: Give me a few seconds to post the whole code, its in my native language, so u wont understand.

Comment: If your input function return 0 on invalid input, does it return another value on success? You could check the return value of the input function in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 if(input(matrix,number) != 0) output(matrix,number); 
 // You don't {} for a single instruction
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: `!= 0` can be omitted.

Answer (score 7):

You may check the return value of `input()` before calling `output()`.
You can use the `exit()` function to terminate the program

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to indicate errors is to throw an exception.

```
int main() {
    ...
    try {
        input(matrix, number);
        output(matrix, number);
    } catch(std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what();
    }
}
```

In input:

```
if ((a[i][j] < 6) || (a[i][j] > 10))
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid input!");
}
```

Comment: You obviously know more about C++ than I do. But I never use exceptions to check if the user input is valid. I use exceptions just for exceptional situations, which should never occur. It is expected that users make nonsensical inputs.

Comment: @Lucas: Program termination is an exceptional condition.

Comment: Is it? Most programs have to terminate at some point. I would make program termination in this case just part of my normal control flow. But I guess it's debatable.

Answer (score 2):

If your input function return 0 on invalid input and another value on success you can run a loop until your input is valid

```
...

while(input(matrix,number) == 0);

...
```

Answer (score 2):

An idiomatic code would be this:

```
while(input (matrix, number)) //idiomatic loop
{
    output (matrix, nubmer);
}
```

The `input()` function should return `false` or `0` when the input is invalid, and `true` or non-zero, when the input is valid.

---

The loop above has the same form as we write `std::istream` idioms:

```
 std::string word;
 while( std::cin >> word ) 
 {
     //..
 }

 //Or

 ifstream file;
 //...
 while( file >> word ) 
 {
     //..
 }

 //Or
 while( std::getline(file, word)) 
 {
     //..
 }
```

I just explained this idiom here, as to how it works:

- [C++ Rewrite a file but leaving out everything before a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404352/c-rewrite-a-file-but-leaving-out-everything-before-a-word/6404383#6404383)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of solutions. One is to declare the `input` function to return an integer. On success `input` can return `0`. On failure (the input is outside the range 6-10) `input` returns a negative number (`-1` for simplicity). Inside your main function, use a while loop to continue calling `input` until it returns 0 for success. Each time `input` fails you can print a message telling the client to enter try again. If you want to exit immediately after the first `input` failure, you can call `exit(1)` inside your `main`.