# delete cout; delete cin; do not give compilation error - a flaw in the Standard library?

Tags: c++, stream, c++11, implicit-conversion

Will the following give a compilation error?

```
delete cout;
delete cin;
```

The answer is : No.

It is a flaw in the implementation of stream classes from the Standard library. They  have the following conversion function to [`void*`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operator_voidpt/) type, which means, all stream objects can be *implicitly* converted to `void*`:

```
operator void * ( ) const;
```

This is very useful in general as it lets us write [very idiomatic loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404352/c-rewrite-a-file-but-leaving-out-everything-before-a-word), say, when reading input from files. But at the same time, it lets user to write `delete stream`. As I said, you can delete any stream object. So all of these are allowed:

```
delete ss;  //declare std::stringstream ss;
delete iss; //declare std::istringstream iss;
delete oss; //declare std::ostringstream oss;
```

Only that they'll give a warning, saying (see at [ideone](http://ideone.com/qdkWO)):

> warning: deleting ‘void*’ is undefined

which you can [easily avoid](http://ideone.com/KZfUR) just by casting, say, to`char*`. But the program has still issue, and most likely will crash when running it.

--

So my question is, has this issue been addressed and fixed, in C++11? The following article provides one fix for this problem:

- [The Safe Bool Idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html)

--

Edit:

From @Xeo's comment on @Alf's answer:

- [Is the safe-bool idiom obsolete in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768/is-the-safe-bool-idiom-obsolete)

The paper which proposed a fix for this issue:

- [Explicit Conversion Operator
  Draft Working Paper 
  Revision 1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2333.html)

Comment: c++ provides you lots of ways to shoot yourself in the foot. This is one of them ;)

Comment: I would say that this is shooting straight between the eyes! :-)

Comment: @VJo: Yes, if it's incorrectly implemented. If you implement Safe Bool Idiom, then you can't shoot yourself in the foot that way.

Comment: Luckily there is a simple workaround available in the language of "Well don't do that then" :)

Comment: @Nawaz: the Safe Bool idiom was invented after C++98 was published (I don't know for C++03) so it's only normal. Note though that they had already thought about it, somewhat, since they used `void*` (which warns in most contexts) rather than `char*` directly or `bool`.

Comment: http://old.nabble.com/-v3---PATCH--Use-explicit-operator-bool-for-std%3A%3Abasic_ios-in-C%2B%2B0x-mode.-td32257515.html

Comment: Shouldn't you be more worried about [`memcpy(cout, cin, 10);`](http://ideone.com/UTSVO)  No warnings whatsoever.

Comment: @Ben: Haha.. that's even better.

Comment: @Nawaz: really nice question. I didn't know about this.

Comment: Well there was one thing I forgot to address, namely, whether a diagnostic is required for `delete p` where `p` is a `void*`. I don't know. But now I have some cooking to attend to, so...

Comment: @BenVoigt: your link about `memcpy(cout,cin,10)` seems to be broken ? Can you upload the working link again ?

Comment: @Destructor: Please complain to the ideone.com team -- they're violating their own public promises about link lifetime but aren't likely to do anything about it unless they get a large volume of requests about it.

Comment: but is `memcpy(cout,cin,10)` undefined behaviour ? What standard says about this ?

Comment: @Destructor: Yes, it is UB. What do *you* expect it to do, BTW?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It has apparently been fixed.

At least, in N3290 you have `std::basic_ios::operator bool` instead of that `void*` conversion, and this `operator bool` is declared **`explicit`**.

Note that C++98/C++03 did not support `explicit` type conversion operators, but C++11 does.

An `explicit` type conversion operator

> **N3290 §12.3.2/2;**
>   is only considered as a user-defined conversion
>   for direct-initialization (8.5)

And that might seem to be impractical for the *condition* in e.g. a `while` or `for` statement.

Happily,

> **N3290 §4/3;**
>   An expression `e` can be *implicitly converted* to a type `T` if and only if the declaration `T t=e;` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t` (8.5). Certain language constructs require that an expression be converted to a Boolean value.
>   An expression `e` appearing in such a context is said to be *contextually converted to `bool`* and is well-formed if and only if the declaration `bool t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t` (8.5). The effect of either implicit conversion is the same as performing the
>   declaration and initialization and then using the temporary variable as the result of the conversion.

where `bool t(e);` is a *direct-initialization*.

E.g. you don’t have to explicit convert a stream object used as condition in a `while`, because there is implicitly an explicit conversion (he he).

Unfortunately, searching N3290 I can’t find any list of the “certain language constructs” where this happens, but in comments to this answer JohannesD wrote:

> Searched through the FDIS for “contextually”, and the whole list seems to be: **`if`**, **`while`**,
>   **`do`**, **`for`**, **`noexcept`**, and **`static_assert`** conditions; the first operand of **`?:`**; both
>   operands of **`&&`** and **`||`**; and the operand of **`!`**.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: So with the `explicit` conversion, can we use it in the `while` loop as we do with C++03 streams?

Comment: Yes, that's the silly C++11 "implicitly explicit". He he. :-)

Comment: @Alf: would you mind expanding your explanation of explicit operators then. I thought that it would require qualification, but apparently it does not... so when can "implicit" conversion take place using the `explicit` operator :x ?

Comment: @Alf: I agree with Matthieu. Please expand your explanation of explicit operators.

Comment: And it has been fixed at the core language side too. The `delete` operator now only considers conversion functions to pointer-to-object types. So instead of such a case having undefined behavior, it now requires a diagnostic. Of course that doesn't require a change on his implementation formally (he already got a diagnostic), but most probably the implementation will now reject instead of merely warn...

Comment: This is part of the Standard conversions i clause 4: "Certain language constructs require that an expression be converted to a Boolean value. An expression `e` appearing in such a context is said to be contextually converted to bool and is well-formed if and only if the declaration `bool t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t`." Obviously Alf finds it amusing that a "contextual conversion" uses an explicit operator to perform what used to be an implicit conversion.

Comment: Searched through the FDIS for "contextually", and the whole list seems to be: `if`, `while`, `do`, `for`, `noexcept`, and `static_assert` conditions; the first operand of `?:`; both operands of `&&` and `||`; and the operand of `!`.

Comment: Related: [Is the safe-bool idiom obsolete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768/is-the-safe-bool-idiom-obsolete).

Comment: @Alf I think you confused me and JohannesD :)

Answer (score 0):

If I can give my 2 cents, I think the standard library "flawed" a bit, with all the good intentions.

The `operator void*()` had been introduced to allow code like
`while(stream)` or `if(!stream)` or `while(stream && ...)`, without giving an implicit access to integer arithmetic (that `operator bool` whould have given).
In fact, this disable integer arithmetic, but gives access to pointer features (like delete ...).

Now, in C++0x, an `explicit oeprator bool()` had been introduced. It doesn't implicitly give access to whatever feature, since it requires an implicit conversion. But ... wait a bit: 'while(bool(stream))' or even `while(static_cast<bool>(stream))` are so wordy...
Operator ! is explicit, and 
'while(!!stream)' looks so effective that I even wonder why not accept this as a paradigm:

If I want something to be explicitly converted into bool, I just provide an `operator!()`
and give to `!` the memaning of "is not valid" and of `!!` as "is valid".

Much safer then an implicit conversion and not uselessly wordy: after all `!` exist from ever!

Comment: You don't have to write `while(!!stream)`, because the `explicit` conversion is invoked implicitly for `while` and other constructs where a `bool` value is expected. See my answer. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: You might want to look up the "safe bool idiom." (Or don't, since it's obsolete with C++11.) I tried going with `!!` for a little while and decided the ugliness wasn't worth the marginal safety…

Comment: @Alf: yes, with new compilers doesn't matter aymore, but with old ... I saw so many tricks just to avoid to type a ! .... Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It's a matter of taste... there are many other ugly things in C++ ...