# which operator overloading has been used for ifstream object to evalute to boolean

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am new to C++. recently I come across the following code

```
ifstream in("somefile");

if(in){
    //read the file....
}
```

I am wondering which operator overloading the ifstream might have used for the in object to automatically evaluate to boolean in if condition. I tried but couldnt find a clue. please help me. thank in advance

Comment: The answer is available here as well : [delete cout; delete cin; do not give compilation error - a flaw in the Standard library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453583/delete-cout-delete-cin-do-not-give-compilation-error-a-flaw-in-the-standard-l)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually [operator void *](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operator_voidpt/).

It's overridden to return a non-zero pointer if the stream is valid, and a `NULL` pointer otherwise. The pointer it returns is meaningless and should not be dereferenced, it's only there to be evaluated in a boolean context.

Answer (score 3):

The void pointer conversion operator is often used for this purpose.  Something similar to

```
struct ifstream {
  typedef void * voidptr;
  operator voidptr() const;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::ifstream` gets its conversion to `bool` from it's base class `std::ios` (`std::basic_ios<char>`) which has conversion function declared:

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

It returns `!fail()`.

(In the previous version of the standard ISO/IEC 14882:2003, `std::basic_ios` had a conversion function `operator void*() const` but this version of the standard has now been withdrawn.)