# integer by integer file reading

Tags: c++

I want to read file so that it should read integer by integer. I have read it line by line but i want to read it integer by integer.

This is my code:

```
void input_class::read_array()
{    
        infile.open ("time.txt");
        while(!infile.eof()) // To get you all the lines.
        {
            string lineString;
            getline(infile,lineString); // Saves the line in STRING
            inputFile+=lineString;
        }
        cout<<inputFile<<endl<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<inputFile[5];

        infile.close();
}
```

Comment: What is the format of the file?  Is it binary?  If not, what are the delimiters between the integer values?

Answer (score 3):

You should do this:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> ints;
int num;
infile.open ("time.txt");
while( infile >> num)
{
    ints.push_back(num);
}
```

The loop will exit when it reaches EOF, or it attempts to read a non-integer. To know in details as to how the loop works, read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219062/whats-preferred-pattern-for-reading-lines-from-a-file-in-c), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404352/c-rewrite-a-file-but-leaving-out-everything-before-a-word) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931535/linux-segmentation-fault-in-c-due-to-the-function-ifstream).

Another way to do that is this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

infile.open ("time.txt");
std::istream_iterator<int> begin(infile), end;
std::vector<int> ints(begin, end); //populate the vector with the input ints
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read from fstream to int using [`operator>>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/):

```
int n;
infile >> n;
```